# Emacs Etags Returning to Starting Buffer/Position

Tags: emacs, etag

I am in buffer A and use M-. on some function name which jumps me to buffer B. From that function, I use M-. again which jumps me to buffer C. Now I have seen what I want and want to go back to buffer A. I don't know of a command to do this without opening the buffer list and finding the buffer I was in or remembering the buffer's name and typing it in. What do you do to solve this?

Answer (score 8):

```
M-*  Pop back to where you previously invoked M-. and friends.
```

from [Emacs Find Tag](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Tag.html).

It basically works like a stack push/pop, like this:

```
      M-.           M-.  
  ---------->   ----------> 
A             B             C
  <----------   <----------
      M-*           M-*
```